# What type of physicist studies quantum physics the most?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, education

I want to become a physicist, and I am particularly interested in quantum physics. I know quantum physics has applications in many branches of physics. Condensed matter physicists use it among others. Is it possible to specialize in quantum physics? And if not what is the closest thing to a quantum physics specialization?
Cosmology? Particle Physics?

Comment: Every single physicist needs to know quantum physics, just like every single physicist must know classical mechanics, electricity and magnetism, and statistical physics. There is no such thing as a specialization in quantum physics. That said, many people don't do quantum mechanical calculations as part of their research/job/every-day-lives; but if you work in condensed matter physics, atomic molecular and optical physics, cosmology, high energy (particle) physics, plasma physics, nuclear physics, material science, quantum information/computing, etc. then you need to know quantum mechanics.

Comment: Quantum mechanics is merely one of many tools for the understanding of physics. When you study physics it will be a small part of a much larger body of knowledge. If you don't know the rest of physics, you will end up knowing next to nothing about quantum mechanics, either, because you will miss the entire context in which it has to be applied. Apart from that nobody will let you graduate, of course, if you don't know the other aspects of the physical world. Don't worry too much about it. You will know soon enough if physics is right for you, or not, once you enter university.

Comment: One more comment, do address your question of "what is the closest thing to a quantum physics specialization?" This is actually a hard question to answer, and different people will have different opinions. My personal opinion is quantum information/computing. But others might choose (not soft) condensed matter physics or high-energy physics, since these branches actually use quantum field theory.